# Вложенные типы данных доступные снаружи, но без возможности создания

Tags: c#, .net

Подскажите, можно ли сделать такой вложенный тип, с которым можно работать из вне(Обращаться к полям и методам), но что бы конструктор не был доступен внешнему коду, а был доступен только внешнему классу в котором объявлен?

Comment: ЕМНИП, такого ни в c# нет, ни в CRL нет поддержки. А зачем вам нужна такая штука, может как-то иначе можно решить исходную задачу? Мне в голову приходит только мысль дать внешнему классу проксирующие методы, но этож какие-то костыли...

Comment: @AK, например, есть внутренний тип, существование которого не имеет смысла вне рамках внешнего типа => не хотелось бы давать возможность свободно создавать тип.

Comment: А какой тогда смысл давать обращаться к полям и методам снаружи, если это сугубо внутренний объект? Пусть внешний сам работает с ним, не демонстрируя миру подробности.

Comment: @AK Данная вещь полезна для установки приватных переменных (вернее скрытого) состояния, что иногда надо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для таких целей служат *интерфейсы*. Выставлять наружу публичные поля в любом случае ай-яй-яй, а вот свойства можно вполне выставить в интерфейсе.

Получаем вот такую конструкцию:

```
class Outer
{
    public IInner CreateInner() { return new Collatz(2017); }

    public interface IInner
    {
        int Curr { get; }
        void Step();
    }

    class Collatz : IInner
    {
        public Collatz(int val) { Curr = val; }
        public int Curr { get; private set; }
        public void Step()
        {
            Curr = (Curr % 2 == 0) ? (Curr / 2) : (Curr * 3 + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

То есть, конструктор спрятан, мы можем снаружи получить лишь интерфейс, который не позволяет сконструировать объект.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Outer outer = new Outer();
        Outer.IInner inner = outer.CreateInner();
        Console.WriteLine(inner.Curr);
        do
        {
            inner.Step();
            Console.WriteLine(inner.Curr);
        } while (inner.Curr > 1);
    }
}
```